# Flutter: draw half circle

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How to draw a half circle like this? 
please, i don`t want a Container widget and change its radius

[image]

Comment: use custom painter or clipper

Comment: yeah i know. i tried to do so but i couldn`t achieve it

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you mean in " i don`t want a Container widget and change its radius", but here is my way to create a half circle:

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(64.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new ClipPath(
                  clipper: new CustomHalfCircleClipper(),
                  child: new Container(
                    height: 300.0,
                    width: 300.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150.0) ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class CustomHalfCircleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
      @override
      Path getClip(Size size) {
        final Path path = new Path();
        path.lineTo(0.0, size.height / 2);
        path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2);
        path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
        return path;
      }
      @override
      bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, if i set the the height to a lower value it will be flattened. in your solution i must maintain width and height ratio

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking a look at this package: [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)

They have several different types of clipping and the one you might be looking for is the **OvalBottomBorderClip** or **OvalTopBorderClip**.

Also, you can take a look on their code (and maths) to create your own.

Answer (score -1):

you can use CustomPainter.

```
class HalfCircle extends CustomPainter{
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center:Offset(size.width/2,size.height/2),radius: 97), 3.14, 3.14, false, customPaint());
    canvas.drawPath(getTrianglePath(size,20, 15), customPaint());
  }

  Path getTrianglePath(Size size,double x, double y) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width/2, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width/2+x, y)
      ..lineTo(size.width/2, y)
      ..lineTo(size.width/2-x, y);
  }

  Paint customPaint(){
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Color(0xff2EA760);
    paint.isAntiAlias = true;
    paint.strokeWidth = 10;
    return paint;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: it is a triangle ,  not a half circle

Answer (score -1):

You only need a `Container`, EASY PEASY:

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(100)),
         color: Colors.red,
         shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
     ),
     height: 35,
     width: 35,
),
```